# Assigning a value to a column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns

I have a data frame like so

```
CategoryNumber
1
2
3
1
3
```

I want create a new column 'Category' that assigns values based on the value in the 'CategoryNumber' column, like so

```
CategoryNumber  Category
1               First Category
2               Second Category
3               Third Category
1               First Category
3               Third Category
```

How do I do so using python and pandas

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CatCodes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.codes.html) straight from pandas.

1. First make a column a category
2. Call `cat.codes`
3. Assign it to your new Column

`df['Category2'] = df['CategoryNumber'].astype('category').cat.codes`

```
   CategoryNumber  Category2
0               1          0
1               2          1
2               3          2
3               1          0
4               3          2
```

If you need to make it A,B,C, etc. look at [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
df['Letters'] = df['Category2'].map(dict(zip(df['Category2'].tolist(),string.ascii_uppercase)))

   CategoryNumber  Category2 Letters
0               1          0       D
1               2          1       B
2               3          2       E
3               1          0       D
4               3          2       E
```

Comment: Thanks MattR, but I want the Category column to consists of alphabets, not numbers

Comment: you would just need to use map again on the numbers :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `map`

```
import string
df.CategoryNumber.map(dict(zip(range(1,26),string.ascii_lowercase)))
Out[472]: 
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
4    c
Name: CategoryNumber, dtype: object
```

Comment: my apologies Wen, its not exactly A,B,C. They're just placeholders for actual category names that I have. Had put A,B,C to simplify the question. Have made the appropriate edits to the question

Comment: @kage77 you should be able to replace the dictionary Wen used with your own mapping dictionary, but you have to tell us how to create the mapping you want!

Comment: @kage77 then using `pd.factorize(df.CategoryNumber)[0]
`